# Apex unit testing - Session cache is only supported in Data Silo tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, cache

I am using platform cache.When I try unit test a Apex method that uses Session Cache, I get the following error:

> cache.Org.OrgCacheException: Failed Cache.Session.get() for key
>   'userContext': Session cache is only supported in Data Silo tests

I want to mock the object in the session cache. how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you *need* SeeAllData=true? If not, use SeeAllData=false and then you don't need to mock it.

Comment: The actual method that I am unit testing needs to read data from Session cache. I made SeeAllData=false , now it will throw null pointer exception as the object on cache is null . Is there a way I can mock the session data in cache ?

Comment: If you're getting a NPE, that means your code does not work correctly. You must not assume that there will be anything in the cache at any point in time.