# Receiving error "Org cache is only supported in Data Silo tests"

Tags: apex, unit-test

I've implemented platform cache, I'm running a test and i received the following error:

> caused by: cache.Org.OrgCacheException: Failed Cache.Org.contains() for key 'timeZones': Org cache is only supported in Data Silo tests

This is the test class, im not using SeeAllData=true.

```
public static testmethod void testReassign(){
    SlaProcess sla = [SELECT Id FROM SlaProcess LIMIT 1];
    Account_Default_Entitlement_Process__c ent = new Account_Default_Entitlement_Process__c();
    ent.Name='Standard1';
    ent.Process_id__c=sla.Id;
    insert ent;

    Account testAccount = new Account(
        Name              = 'test',
        BillingCountry = 'United States',
        BillingState = 'Alabama',
        Customer_Type__c = 'Customer',
        Industry = 'Automotive',
        Billing_Account_ID__c = '123456'
    );
    insert testAccount;

    User userTDR = TestUtil.getTDRUser('TDRUser');
    User userSE = TestUtil.getSalesEngenerUser('SEUser'); 
    insert New List<User>{userTDR,userSE};

    Opportunity testOpty = new Opportunity();
    testOpty.StageName = 'Discover';
    testOpty.CloseDate = System.today()+1;
    testOpty.AccountId=testAccount.Id;
    testOpty.Name='testOpty';
    testOpty.Type = 'testType';
    testOpty.Sales_Engineer__C = userSE.Id;
    testOpty.TDR__c = userTDR.Id;
    insert testOpty;

    MassReassignOpportunitiesController controller = new MassReassignOpportunitiesController();
    controller.refreshOptyList();
    controller.filterId = controller.listviewoptions[1].getValue();
    controller.refreshOptyList();
    controller.searchRecord.stageName = 'Discover';
    controller.helperRecord.ClosedDate_From__c=System.today();
    controller.helperRecord.ClosedDate_To__c=System.today()+2;
    controller.helperRecord.From__c=System.today();
    controller.helperRecord.To__c=System.today()+1;
    controller.searchRecord.Type = 'testType';
    controller.refreshOptyListBySearch();

    System.assert(controller.optyList.size()>0);

    controller.optyList[0].selected = true;
    controller.helperRecord.Assign_to__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    controller.Assign();
}
```

what are data silo tests? how can i solve this?
i saw this thread but it didnt help: [Apex unit testing - Session cache is only supported in Data Silo tests](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186391/apex-unit-testing-session-cache-is-only-supported-in-data-silo-tests)

Comment: What API Version is your test class?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Didnt even think about looking at that.
it's an old test class. i re-wrote it to version 38 and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests see all data by default for any API  Version below 24. Set your version to a more recent value and your test will run with data silo.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked when I removed the (SeeAllData=true) portion.

Comment: And you should basically never be using `SeeAllData=true`. There are only a few scenarios where it is truly needed. If you don't know if you need it, then you don't need it (i.e. only use it when you are absolutely sure that it is required). For everything else, you should be creating all of the necessary  data for the test inside of the test class itself.